# Filtering Elastic Beanstalk SNS topic

Tags: filter, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I have an SNS topic for my ElasticBeanstalk instance. Deployments and health status transitions are posted to this topic, `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:309321511178:ElasticBeanstalkNotifications-Environment-Myapp`.
Next a lambda function subscribes to the topic and posts to a slack channel.

However, I'd like to filter these messages to only deployments and transitions to Severe status.

I guess the filter policy of the SNS topic would be the way to do this, but I'm not sure exactly what JSON would be needed to get the results I desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can set monitoring in EB with a threshold "Maximum Environment Health">=20.

Below are the values for different status:

```
0 (Ok), 1 (Info), 5 (Unknown), 10 (No data), 15 (Warning), 20 (Degraded), 25 (Severe)
```